# Using the proper pronoun

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, verbs, sentence-structure, pronouns

I was wondering which preposition is more idiomatic here:

> - To get a shuttle taxi all you have to do is to stand beside the street and just look interested. If a taxi driver wants to pick you up, ..... **speed(s) down** and **turn(s) close** and the driver looks at you.

a. he / she 
b. they 
c. it

To me they all work properly, but it is important to define which one sounds more idiomatic to native speakers so that I know weather I have to add the third person "s" at the end of the following verbs or not.

Comment: Speeds down is not idiomatic. Use slows down. Turns close is also not idiomatic. You may mean pulls over or turns towards you.

Comment: Many thanks @Peter. Just may I ask you if "pulling over" means to move the car to the side of a road (and stop) while in my case, the driver just gets close to you with very low speed to hear your destination name from you. Don't you think neither "pull over", "turn close" nor "turn toward" work here and I have to use verbs like "approach" or just "get close" here?

Comment: To pull over is to move to the passenger's side of the road (left in UK, right in US) and stop moving. Often, especially in the situation you describe, the engine will be left running and the driver will stay seated. In your situation the driver must be prepared to stop in case the conversation takes more than a second. Pulls in to the kerb might be possible, or perhaps crawls along next to the kerb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "it", which would be taken to refer to the taxi itself. If you use "he", "she", or "they" you would not also use "the driver" later on; you might say "and then look(s) at you". These days "they" with the plural forms of the verbs is probably the best choice.

Please note my comment about other aspects of the sentence as well.